# Why computer takes more time in arranging different permutations?

Tags: sorting, c++11, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I just learned the heap's algorithm. Well the larger the number of objects get the more time the system takes to arrange them in all possible permutations. 
But when i calculate the the factorial of that number of objects in a calculator the results are instant.
Why does it happen that same no. of permutations take more time than calculating the factorial?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int len;
   void swap (int *x, int *y)
  {
     int temp;
     temp = *x;
     *x = *y;
     *y = temp;
  }
   void print(const int *v)
  {
     int i;
     int size = len;
     if (v != 0) {
     for ( i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     cout<< v[i] ;
}
cout<<'\n';
}
}
void heappermute(int v[], int n) {
int i;
if (n == 1) {
    print(v);
}
else {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        heappermute(v, n-1);
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            swap(&v[0], &v[n-1]);
    }
        else {
            swap(&v[i], &v[n-1]);
        }
   }
  }
 }

 int main()
 {
  int num[11];
  int  i;
  cout<<"How many numbers you want to enter: ";
  cin>>len;
  cout<<"\nEnter the numbers: ";
  for ( i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
   cin>>num[i];
  heappermute(num, len);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: How are you calculating the permutations? Show code. I suspect one approach may be generating all the permutations and counting them, which is a lot more expensive that doing the math to figure out how many there would be.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have written the code. This is what i used.

Comment: `printf` and `scanf` are usually not welcome in C++.

Comment: @VermillionAzure: There is not a single C++ specific thing in this code; wondering if it's really meant to be C or C11 or something and the tag is wrong.

Comment: Also, your `swap` method is swapping `int` with `char` values, where the inputs are all pointing to `int` data, you're going to get all kinds of data loss here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving two different tasks to your computer program and to your calculator.  Generating every possible permutation of a set of objects is a different problem from finding the number of such permutations.

How many positive even numbers are there below one billion?  What are they?  (List them all.)  Which one takes longer to figure out?

There are ways to calculate a factorial other than listing all the possibilities.  See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14456/factorial-algorithm-more-efficient-than-naive-multiplication) that gives both the naive recursive approach (F(n) = *n**F(*n*-1)) which is Omega(*n*<sup>2</sup> log *n*) and also an O(*n* log *n* log log *n*) algorithm.

A factorial can also be estimated, which may be close enough.  I don't know exactly what method your calculator is using, but one possibility is [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).